# Taking advantage of ES6 default parameters with Mongo

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ecmascript-6

I am wondering if there is a way I can construct mongo's queries to take advantage of es6 default parameters. I have the following method. I want to return all the data if make, model and year is not specified. I am trying to find an elegant solution but so far all I can think of is manual if else.

```
getStyles({ make = '', model = '', year = '-1' }) {
        return this.db
            .collection('styles')
            .find({ 'make.niceName': make, 'model.niceName': model, 'year.year': parseInt(year) })
            .toArray();
    }
```

**Note:** 
This is causing some confusion. I am using destructing on purpose. The problem is not how to write this function. The problem is how to construct a mongo query so it would ignore empty values.

Comment: Uh, `.find({ 'make.niceName': (make||""), ...`

Comment: Isn't that the same as default params.

Comment: @adeneo & Yasin: No, that isn't the same as default parameters.

Comment: Is `getStyles` your own method? And did you intend to do destructuring there?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I know, it was a suggestion for a somewhat elegant solution

Comment: Yes getStyles is my method.

Comment: Is `getStyles` even a function, and does it accept an object as it's only argument?

Comment: You'd think you'd generally do something like -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/sprwf1vb/1/

Comment: Yeah it takes in an object and I am only interested in those three fields. By the way this doesn't work. `.find({ 'make.niceName': (make||""),`. I still don't know how that is different than what I am already doing.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `getStyles` is your own method, sure, you can give `make`, `model`, and `year` defaults. You can also give a default for the whole object you're destructuring so caller doesn't have to pass *anything*:

```
function getStyles({make = '', model = '', year = '-1'} = {}) {
// Overall default ------------------------------------^^^^^
    return // ...
}
```

> The question is not how to organize/write my function but how to use es6 features to write a cleaner code that would work with mongo. I.E if the user didn't pass anything I want to return all the styles but mongo actually looks for empty fields so it doesn't return anything.

It sounds to me like you **don't** want default parameters (except perhaps the overall default). Instead, you want to automate how you build the object you pass `find`.

Given your code example, you can readily do that with `Object.keys` on your object. So accept as an object, e.g.:

```
function getStyles(options = {}) {
```

...an then build your `find` options based on `options`:

```
const findParams = {};
Object.keys(options).forEach(key => {
  findParams[key + ".niceName"] = options[key];
});
```

Live example:

```js
function getStyles(options = {}) {
  const findParams = {};
  Object.keys(options).forEach(key => {
    findParams[key + ".niceName"] = options[key];
  });
  console.log(`find options: ${JSON.stringify(findParams)}`);
}

let results = getStyles({make: "Ford", model: "Mustang"});
results = getStyles({make: "Ford", model: "Mustang", year: 2017});
```

If the mapping of the name you accept (`make`) to the name you need for `find` (`make.niceName`) isn't as easy as just appending `.niceName`, it's easy enough to have a `Map` (or just object) you build once:

```
const paramNames = new Map([
  ["make", "make.niceName"],
  ["model", "model.niceName"],
  ["year", "year.niceName"]
]);
```

...and then use:

```
const findParams = {};
Object.keys(options).forEach(key => {
  const paramName = paramNames.get(key);
  if (paramName) {
    findParams[paramName] = options[key];
  }
});
```

Live example:

```js
const paramNames = new Map([
  ["make", "make.niceName"],
  ["model", "model.niceName"],
  ["year", "year.niceName"]
]);

function getStyles(options = {}) {
  const findParams = {};
  Object.keys(options).forEach(key => {
    const paramName = paramNames.get(key);
    if (paramName) {
      findParams[paramName] = options[key];
    }
  });
  console.log(`find options: ${JSON.stringify(findParams)}`);
}

let results = getStyles({make: "Ford", model: "Mustang"});
results = getStyles({make: "Ford", model: "Mustang", year: 2017});
```

---

Side note: Defaults don't have to be strings, so if you use numbers for `year` rather than strings, your default would just be `-1`, not `'-1'`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I do intent on using destructuring with defaults. The question is not how to organize/write my function but how to use es6 features to write a cleaner code that would work with mongo. I.E if the user didn't pass anything I want to return all the styles but mongo actually looks for empty fields so it doesn't return anything.

Comment: I understand that I can use integers but choose not to, to keep it consistent with actual data. The year field will always be a string.

Comment: If you pass an empty string, Mongo looks for an empty string. If you want to return all matches, you leave that key/value pair out of the query.

Comment: @YasinYaqoobi: Sounds like you *don't* want default parameters. :-) I've updated the answer.